# Javascript RegEx: capture -A but not A-A. where A is any letter in the set [A-Za-z]. dash followed by letter passes, dash surrounded by letters doesnt

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

Example:
`let stringTest = "-this -andthis but-not-this"`

`// match = ['-this', '-andthis']`
and ignore "but-not-this"

so I want to capture anything defined by
`-[A-Za-z]+`

Here is my attempt to ignore the A-A situation: 
`[^([A-Za-z]-[A-Za-z])]`

I see this as match anything except for any letter followed by a dash followed by any letter.

It doesnt work as expected (problem with nesting characters sets within a negation set?) nor do I know how to combine it with the expression that matches -A

Is this possible? Part of my confusion is in understanding how to nest character sets and/or characters groups within the negation character set `[^ignoreStuffHere]`

Thanks in advance

It may help to explain why:

I am receiving strings containing "flag" "data" pairs
where a flag is `-flag` and the data associated with that flag is the following non-flag characters/words

for example

`-flag1 data1 data1 can be long -flag2 data2 -flag3 data3-has dashes in it but isnt a flag`

and I am trying to split this up and store them as flag+data sub strings

```
const pairsArray = arguments.slice(arguments.indexOf('-'))
        .replace(/(\ -)/g, '-')
        .split(/-/g)
        .splice(1);
```

where the pairsArray for the example above SHOULD look like:

```
pairsArray = ['flag1 data1 data1 can be long',
 'flag2 data2',
 'flag3 data3-has dashes in it but isnt a flag' 
]
```

instead it is considering each dash surrounded by letters (data with dashes, not flags) and splitting those up

```
pairsArray = ['flag1 data1 data1 can be long',
 'flag2 data2',
 'flag3 data3',
 '-has dashes in it but isnt a flag' 
]
```

Comment: can you tell what character are you trying to ignore and your desired output !?

Comment: I want to ignore any case where a dash has an alpha character before AND after it

examples:

a-a
abc-abc
etc

Comment: `/\B-[a-z]+|[a-z]+-\B/gi`  you didn't give an example for it but your words imply you also want `andthis-`

Comment: `/(?:^|\s)(-[a-z].*?)(?=\s-|$)/gi`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about?

```js
let stringTest = "-this -andthis but-not-this";

console.log(
  stringTest.match(/(?:^| )-[A-Za-z]+/g).map(s => s.trim())
)
```

For the updated case, you could try `split` on the space that is followed by a dash:

```js
var stringTest = "-flag1 data1 data1 can be long -flag2 data2 -flag3 data3-has dashes in it but isnt a flag"

console.log(
  stringTest.split(/ (?=-)/)
)

// if you don't want to keep the dash at all

console.log(
  stringTest.split(/ -/).map(s => s.replace(/^-/, ""))
)
```

Comment: Man I'm sorry I should have clarified with my actual use case. Would you mind looking at the example I added?

Comment: It seems to work but ignores the first flag/data pair. Here is an example

https://jsfiddle.net/ub5qd52r/

Comment: I am no expert at regex so forgive me trying to decode what you wrote. But i think that it is expecting a space before the dash so it misses the first flag/data pair since it is the beginning of the string and there is no space before the dash there

Comment: Remove the `splice(1)` at the end of pipe, it drops the first element.

Comment: you're absolutely right. I had put there there because originally it was splitting and the first element was a "". I could not figure out why so I was splicing it out.

Comment: Man thank you so much. You have no idea how long I've spent trying to figure this out. I still don't fully understand how the split regex works. I read MDN and I practiced all day on regex101 but it those look ahead type expressions elude me. 

Anyways I ended up using a combination of the first split and then mapping to replace /-/ with '' because your second example relied on that prefixed space which the first flag doesnt have. Code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ub5qd52r/

Comment: As an aside since you are clearly a wizard - do you know if its possible to nest character sets within one another? In the case you want to use the negation character set [^] but with other sets within it like [^[A-Za-z]-[A-Za-z]] to ignore the A-A situation? I know your approach is correct but just for peace of mind id like to learn about nesting. couldnt find anything online about it but i am probably searching the wrong terms

Comment: You can definitely do something like that, see [regex subtraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) here. But it probably doesn't do things to avoid `A-A`, you will need something like `(.)-(?!\1)` to avoid match like that. `?!` is [negative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)